# How to put a border under a title in Libreoffice writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

There is a way to create a new style ( let's call it BorderTitle ) and create a title with a border (an horizontal line) under it?

Something like the line displayed here:

[image]

Comment: Are you doing this with code? If not, I'm not sure this is on topic for this site, because it is unrelated to programming. If so, please add what you have so far to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question, simple answer: **yes**.

---

Now you want to know *how to do this*, don't you?

I suggest to select an existing paragraph style in the Navigator and (per right-click context menu) create a new one from it. Choose a good name. In the properties dialogue select the border tab and switch on the border at the bottom. Adjust anything else you like.

Comment: For border options there is no bottom only option, bottom and top. My version is libreoffice writer version 6.1.3.2

Comment: I just click at the bottom border at "user defined". My LO is 6.3.6.2.